# htaccess, folder to folder redirect has some problems

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem redirecting a folder to another one.
The rule seems to "work" but it stumble at some point adding some other stuff.
Here an example:

The goal is to redirect traffic from oldfolder (not existing anymore) to newfolder.

www.domain.com/one/**oldfolder**/year/  -->  www.domain.com/one/**newfolder**/year/

So i set up the following rules (first one for the canonical url):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/oldfolder/(.*)$ $1/newfolder/$2 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that it redirects to:

http://www.domain.com/home/username/public_html/www.domain.com/one/newfolder/year/

Anyone can spot the problem in the rule i wrote?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check your DocumentRoot
2. Check the Directory directive
3. Make sure you have `RewriteBase /` if this .htaccess file is in your document root.

Comment: The rule you suggested: "RewriteBase /" Solved the problem.
Thank you very much!